# Scriptable web browsing

Tags: internet

One of my most common tasks is:

1) Open a bunch of tabs

2) Copy and paste the URL from the address bar, as well as the body text, of each open tab into a text editor

Is there a way to script this from the Linux shell, even though I'm browsing in the GUI?

I get tired of having to do it all the time.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? Are the URLs in the address bar or in the body of the page? It might make a difference what browser you're using. The usual way to script retrieval and parsing of web pages is to start by retrieving the page using `curl` or `wget`. You don't say which operating system, but your use of the word "shell" seems to imply Linux/Unix. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility, if you don't mind downloading the same URLs twice, is to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
for url in 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html' \
       'http://superuser.com/questions/239935/scriptable-web-browsing' 
       # and so on
do
    TMPFILENAME=$(mktemp)
    firefox "$url"   # or whatever browser you want that is set to open
                     # links in a new tab
    echo "$url" > $TMPFILENAME
    lynx -dump "$url" >> $TMPFILENAME
    kate $TMPFILENAME &  # or any other text editor that is set to open
                         # files in a new tab
done
```